# Redux: parameter in url is undefined

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, redux, react-redux, redux-framework

In my redux app I created this function, that calls an API from the backend:

```
export function submitfunction(first, second) {
return {
type: 'SUBMIT_JOINT',
meta: {
  API_METHOD: 'POST',
  API_CALL: `api/${first.ref}/check`,
  API_PAYLOAD: [{ first, second }],
  API_SUCCESS: 'SUBMIT_SUCCESS',
  API_ERRORS: {
    400: 'SUBMIT_ERROR',
    404: 'SUBMIT_ERROR',
    403: 'SUBMIT_ERROR',
    500: 'SUBMIT_ERROR',
  },
},
};
}
```

I want to pass `first.ref` as a parameter in my URL. When I call this function I find that `first.ref` is undefined. But, when I look in my payloads `first.ref` has a specific value. The result of my debugger when I call this function:

```
type(pin): "SUBMIT_JOINT"
▶meta(pin)
API_METHOD(pin): "POST"
API_CALL(pin): "api/undefined/check"
▶API_PAYLOAD(pin)
▶0(pin): { ref: "M54df",  … }
▶1(pin): { ref: "54233", birthCountry: "MA", … }
```

Can you please tell me how to pass "M54df" in the URL, instead of undefined?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using polyfill or transpiling your your code to ES5? Using template literal `` `api/${first.ref}/check` `` is an ES6 feature and some browsers might not support it.

Try using `'api/' + first.ref + '/check'` to see if it's still a problem